# number of sub-sequence starting with i

Tags: combinatorics

Lets say i have N number from 1 to N, and i have to find out all the sub-sequence of this number. but i am interested in finding out that how many sub-sequence will be there which start with 1 or 2 or 3 ..... N. for example

```
lets say i have three numbers 1,2,3
so all the sub-sequence will be [1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3] (all the sub-sequence are sorted)
```

Here we can see

`number of sub-sequence starting with 1 -> 4`

`number of sub-sequence starting with 2 -> 2`

`number of sub-sequence starting with 3 -> 1`

is there any formula or algorithms to achieve this. I can also find the answer by finding all the sub-sequence. but time complexity is exponential.

Comment: Starting with $1\le i \le N$ , there are $2^{N-i}$ subsequences.

Comment: after seeing this i realised that it was so obvious. thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the $S_i$ set of subsequences of $1, ..., n$ which begin with $i$, where $1 \leq i \leq n$. Now consider the set $J_i = P(\{i+1, ..., n\})$. I claim that $2^{n - i} = |J_i| = |S_i|$; that is, there are $2^{n-i}$ such subsequences.

For consider the function $f : J_i \to S_i$ defined as follows: consider $s \in J_i$. Then let $f(s)$ be the sequence beginning with $i$ and followed by all the elements of $s$ in order. This is an element of $S_i$.

And consider the function $g : S_i \to J_i$. Given a sequence $w \in S_i$, define $g(w) = \{j: $ $j > i$ and $j$ occurs in $w\}$.

Clearly, $f$ and $g$ are two-sided inverses.